# When should I use the bignumber library?

Tags: javascript, bignum

I am trying to understand when to use the bignumber library.

Question 1). As we know, JavaScript has an upper limitation on the Number type which is 2^53, but it also has another type, BigInt, which doesn't have a limit. Why would we use the bignumber library? Is it because it also works with decimals? Are there any other reasons?

Question 2) Let's say I have a `x = new BigNumber(10000000000000000000);` and now I want to multiply this by 30. Should I also transform 30 to `BigNumber` first and then multiply or would this be okay: `30 * x`?  It seems like that I didn't transform 30 to `BigNumber` and it still works correctly. When should I use `mul` from the bignumber library?

Comment: It's a library, you would use it if it does what you want.  There is no hard and fast rule here.   You could use BigInt to handle decimals if you wanted.

Comment: The question is that why does it exist ? what things does it make easier ?

Comment: It exists, in the same way moment.js exists, some people may rather handle dates in a different way, to how to do it in pure JS.  But the biggest reason (pardon the pun) it exists is likely due to the fact BigInt hasn't always been part of JS, and I believe BigNumber has been around for a lot longer.  And if your still wanting to target ie11, you might want to use it, but personally I would transpile and polyfill if that was the case.

Comment: If you want the Question to include "why does it exist", then you should edit your Question. Though it's going to be bordering being opinion based, since why something exists is usually only something designers can answer.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question and why it's down voted and closed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why would we use bignumber library? is it because it also works with decimals?

Yes. A big*number* library typically works with arbitrary-precision floating-point numbers, while a big*int* library (or also the builtin data type) can only handle integers.
In addition, there are quite a few libraries that implement big integer math which came into existence before the native support of `BigInt` in JavaScript, a rather recent addition to the language. This also means a library is necessary in older browsers.

> Now I want to multiply this by 30. Should I also transform 30 to bigNumber first?

No, this is usually not necessary (but of course depends on the library).

> would this would be okay: `30 * x`?

No, that would not be ok. If you're working with a bignumer library, you will need to use its methods (like `x.multiply(30)`), not the `*` operator which only works with JavaScript's builtin data types.